# Interpolation of data with dynamic size

Tags: c#, algorithm, interpolation

I have a program that displays audio visualizations using FFT. The data I get from the FFT converted to decibels and weighted.

This data will later be plotted giving a similar result to this:

[image]

The problem I'm having is that I want to be able to select what frequency range the bars display, as well as the number of bars which displays the data.

Say I want to draw 100-1500Hz and display this data on 256 bars, I get the indexes of those frequencies with this formula:

```
(int)(desiredFrequency / (samplerate / FFTsize / 2.0)); // samplerate usually 44100Hz, and FFTsize can vary, but in my case 2048
```

I can then easily plug the values in and get my index-range from the decibel-array.

In this example my start index would be `100 / (44100 / 2048 / 2)` rounded downward, which gives me 9. The end index would be 1500 / .... = 140 (I round up here since I want to make sure the frequency is present).

```
public float[] Interpolate(float[] inData)
{
    int upperFrequencyIndex = 140;
    int lowerFrequencyIndex = 9;
    int barCount = 256;
    int count = upperFrequencyIndex - lowerFrequencyIndex;

    float[] data = inData.Skip(lowerFrequencyIndex).Take(count).ToArray();
    // now I have the desired range in a float array. This is the decibel data which will be interpolated.

    float[] outData = new float[barCount];
    // and here is the array which will hold the interpolated data.

    // ????

    return outData;
}
```

Notice that `barCount > count` which means there more bars per point of data and that the ratio between these almost always won't be an integer. One thing to note is that there might be scenarios where `barCount < count`, which only adds to my already humongous headache.

How can interpolation be calculated with two varying sized-arrays (one being the range from the decibel data, and the other one being the number of bars' which also can change. Both of which, though, is a float array)

Some pointers to the right direction in any form would really be appreciated here. My mind just doesn't understand this..

Answer (score 0):

Well, given how little information you've given us about your actual data and structures we cannot give you an explicit answer, however here is the general idea and approach to interpolate from a source histogram to a target(output) histogram:

A histogram (bar chart) consist of bars that have a value (Y) and each represent an input range (X(i) to X(i+1)).  To interpolate a specific bar in the target:

1. sum all of the source bars whose ranges are completely within the range of the of the target bar (this may be zero bars)
2. sum any bars (at the high and low ends) of the source that may be only partially within the target range, *but* weight each of them according to how much of their source range is within the target range
3. divide this total by the number of source bars including the partial weights for any end bars.

This then is the value to use for the target bar.  Repeat this for every target bar in the target histogram.

Comment: Hi @rbarryyoung , I get that I need to take the average between two numbers in my decibel-array and plug them in to the output. Though I do not understand how this would work when the number of elements in the decibel array divided by the number of bars isn't an integer. I will update my question with more information about what I mean.